# Image used in html email template not turning up in email

Tags: email-template

I have used an html email template to send an email, which is having an image attached to it which is stored in "Shared Documents" folder.

But the recipient of the email is not getting the image,
The code being used by me to send image is as follows :

```
<img alt="" src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01511000000kqAz">
```

Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to use the full URL when adding images to email templates.

i.e.  `https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01511000000kqAz`

When an external user (someone that can't log into your salesforce) views an email, each and every image needs to be accessible with a full URL.

Make sure the document is "Externally Available".

For more information:  [Adding Images to Email Templates](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_template_images.htm)

Answer (score 0):

https://nax.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=XXXXXXXXXXX&oid=XXXXXXX" height="90" width="600"/>

replace nax with your salesforce instance
replace id with the record ID of your document. (see instructions by EIE50 above )
replace oid with your org id found in Settings > Company Profile >Company Info